# Angel from Montgomery

Tags: idioms

Regarding the *John Prine* song entitled *Angel from Montgomery*, I’ve read online that *Angel From Montgomery*  might be related to a pardon from Governor but was wondering if that’s a standard idiom or just one fan’s interpretation in the fan website:

> Angel From Montgomery notes.
> An "Angel from Montgomery" refers to a pardon for a prison sentence from the governor. It is also used to refer to a last minute pardon from the death sentence. The phrase originated in Alabama where the capital is Montgomery. 
> The way John puts it the woman is living in her own self made prison that she can't escape from, hence she needs a pardon (the angel from Montgomery). 
> — [jpshrine.org](https://www.jpshrine.org/lyrics/songs/trivia/angelfrommontgomery_t.htm)

Is this reliable ? Was it a real idiom before Prine wrote the song in 1970? There is no mention of this pardon interpretation at [wikipedia entry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel_from_Montgomery) for the song.

PS. Please, before you hit close vote I am not simply asking for a lyrics interpretation, I am asking whether it’s an idiom, and explaining as background where I encountered it!

Comment: Google Books shows no usage before 1970.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=angel+from+Montgomery%2C&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cangel%20from%20Montgomery%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BAngel%20from%20Montgomery%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAngel%20From%20Montgomery%3B%2Cc0

Comment: “*Eddie Holstein thinks I got it from the angel down on Michigan Boulevard [in Chicago] There was evidently a gargoyle that came out from the Montgomery Wards building.*” https://americansongwriter.com/john-prine-angel-from-montgomery-behind-the-song/